# How do I write a Latex formula in the legend of a plot using Matplotlib inside a .py file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am writing a script in Python (.py file) and I am using Matplotlib to plot an array.
I want to add a legend with a formula to the plot, but I haven't been able to do it.
I have done this before in IPython or the terminal. In this case, writing something like this:

```
legend(ur'$The_formula$')
```

worked perfectly. However, this doesn't work when I call my .py script from the terminal/IPython.

Comment: [matplotlib docs: Rendering math equations using TeX](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html)

Comment: [LATEX Mathematical Symbols](https://www.caam.rice.edu/~heinken/latex/symbols.pdf)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The easiest way is to assign the label when you plot the data, 
e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.gca()  # or any other way to get an axis object
ax.plot(x, y, label=r'$\sin (x)$')

ax.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked fine. Except for the fact that 'r' IS necessary when you want to write a formula in a legend/axis.

Comment: what version of python and mpl are you using?  If I used `ax.plot(x,y,label=r'$\sin (x)$')`, I get `LaTeX` errors with '$\\sin$'. (I'm 2.7.3 python and bleeding edge mpl)

Comment: I use Python 2.7.3 and Mpl 1.1.1.

Comment: If one uses `black` auto formatting, the single quotes automatically get converted to double quotes. That breaks the latex interpretation and displays the characters as they are. To circumvent this, one could instead type: `label=r"""$\sin (x)$"""`

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy, because the docs don't use the usual `$ ... $`, so I assumend they weren't needed, but they totally are. Regarding `black` (which I don't use) and `"` which I do: For me `"` does work. `r"$CO_{2}$"` renders as expected (matplotlib 3.5.1, python 3.9.7)

Comment: Also `'\varphi'` will be interpreted before latex conversion as `\v` + `arphi`. Must be written `r'\varphi'`

Answer (score 13):

When writing code for labels it is:

```
import pylab

# code here

pylab.plot(x,y,'f:', '$sin(x)$')
```

So perhaps `pylab.legend('$latex here$')`

Edit:

The `u` is for unicode strings, try just `r'$\latex$'`