# Cannot print $ in matplotlib text

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I am trying to place a text string with two dollar signs ($) on a figure generated in python3 with matplotlib. I am running on a mac with the default mac backend.  I also tried TKAgg with the same results.

This is my sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

text = "first $" + str(10.95) + ", second $" + str(20.99)
print (text)

plt_text = plt.text(0.5,0.5,text,va='center',ha='center')

plt.show()
```

The desired output is "first $10.95, second $20.99".
Instead, I get:
["first 10.95, second20.99](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0WEN.png)
In case the image is not available, I might note that the word second is changed to italics. The print(text) works correctly to the console.

If the string only contains one $, it shows correctly.  If I use double dollar signs ($$) I get an error.  Different combinations of single and double dollar signs did not show correctly.

Comment: Does this work `text = "first \$" + str(10.95) + ", second \$" + str(20.99)`

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matploitlib assumes the dollar sign($) is a Latex symbol, to indicate the beginning or the end of a latex. You need to escape it to print it as any other character. [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016217/how-do-i-write-a-latex-formula-in-the-legend-of-a-plot-using-matplotlib-inside-a)

```py
text = "first \$" + str(10.95) + ", second \$" + str(20.99)
```